Gradle Sync Failure: Unsupported Class File Major Version 65 - Incompatible Java and Gradle Versions in Flutter Project
enter image description here
while running my app in my phone i am getting the above error in the image
i tried upgrading gradle updating my android studio upgrading my
gradle-wrapper.properties to distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip
and was expecting to solve the error but i was getting some another error

Please don't post error text messages as screenshot. Just copy and paste the text and include it in your question.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I recommend to open only the "android" folder of your flutter project with Android Studio and wait until the IDE automatically download and install the gradle. Let us know the result in comments.

If you’ve upgraded to Android Studio Ladybug (2024.2.1) you’ll need to update the Gradle plugin as well
Please follow this link and make sure to use version 8.5 or 8.9
Compatibility Matrix
If upgrading Gradle causes any issues with older Kotlin or Java libraries, you might need to update those libraries as well.
In my case, I encountered problems because some Kotlin libraries didn’t have updates available yet. To resolve the issue, I had to downgrade both Android Studio and Flutter by one version. Upgrading the project could also lead to namespace issues in Kotlin/Java libraries.
You can open the android folder separately in Android Studio and use the Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) to upgrade the project.
It might take some time for everything to stabilise, but I hope this helps.
